# Selecting different nuget packages based on buildConfiguration

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a Internal framework that i build in two different versions, for different versions of an external system.

I build this and publishes them to a NuGet feed as "Framework-Ver1" and "Framework-Ver2".

In the Application i have that is using this framework i have Added this to the csproj.

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_Ver2' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Framework.Ver2" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_Ver1'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Framework.Ver1" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

This works fine in Visual Studio.

On Azure Devops though i always get Framework.Ver2.

When I'm Checking it out the DevOps yaml looks like this

```
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release_Ver1'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'GUID'
```

But, configuration is not used by the restore command according to the documentation.

if i change the "default" in the csproj, it changes in what it uses but for both pipelines. This confirms that no buildConfiguration is sent into the fetch process.

```
 <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```

is changed to

```
 <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release_Ver1</Configuration>
```

Edit: This last piece gives me an idea, using a Env-variable for the default... ^^

Comment: Can you post the rest of your YAML, or at least the variable/parameter declarations for `$(solution)` and `$(buildConfiguration)`?

Comment: I've added the variables.

Comment: Great. Now it's easier to see your intent. Can you queue a release with the diagnostics checkbox set? It will provide more detail about what the task is trying to do. If that doesn't work, we can set the `verbosityRestore` parameter to the task itself to get more details.

Comment: Ok, a pastebin of the log is https://pastebin.com/wk4mMLVB

ITCO.SboAddon.Framework.SBO10 is Framework.Ver2 in my example above.
Release_SBO9 is Release_Ver1 in example above..

(Simplified the example.)

Comment: Thanks for the help @WaitingForGuacamole, found a solution and posted it as an answer down below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing how the default in csproj is set solved the problem.

In the beginning of the csproj i added:

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">$(buildConfiguration)</Configuration>
```

And since the yaml have:

```
buildConfiguration: 'Release_Ver1'
```

That is used during NuGet Restore.